# Debugger for C for linux

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to find a decent debugger for C with a GUI interface that allows me to do atleast the usual stuff of setting break points, stepping over each line of code. I'm having a hard time finding one,(GDB command line didn't do good) and what's more, I'm on ubuntu not windows, so I wonder if there is such a debugger.

Comment: There are a couple of simplified IDEs for Linux that support C with a symbolic debugger.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688220/ide-for-debugging-c-source-in-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596575/good-c-debugging-ide-environment-for-linux and https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-ide-editors-source-code-editors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is a cross platform IDE which gives you a GUI wrapper to gdb, as well as providing a lot of development help - it is free, gratis & open source.

You can:

- Set breakpoints
- Step through the code
- Inspect values
- etc.

[image]

Comment: The problem with codeblocks' debugger is that it lets debug only on projects and not in empty files, and doing that always(making a project for each file to debug is a bit annoying), the problem is same for netbeans. VScode's debugger seemed descent but, I'm not being able to configure it for C(Some file open continuous errors))

Comment: Plus, I couldn't find the column that tells us the variable values or the stack trace in codeblock.

Comment: For your first issue you can attach to a running process see http://www.dummies.com/programming/cpp/attaching-to-a-running-process-using-codeblocks/ - if you tell it where the source code is then things go a lot easier.

Comment: To inspect a given variable when you are at a break point hover over it in the source code, you can also right click and add to the watches on the right side of the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs provides a graphical interface to GDB, as well as other debuggers, through its [Grand Unified Debugger (GUD) library](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Debuggers.html).